# How do I select all distinct strings in a list of lists of another type?

Tags: c#, linq, list

I'm still very new with LINQ. I have the following "simplified" data structure:

```
List<List<Field>> myData = new List<List<Field>>();
```

`Field` consists of two string members, `Type` and `Name`.

My goal is to get a `List<string>` containing all distinct `Name` corresponding to a given `Type`. My first approach is this:

```
var test = myData
  .Where(a => a.FindAll(b => b.Type.Equals("testType"))
  .Select(c => c.Name)
  .Distinct());
```

Does somebody have a hint for me? =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to use `SelectMany` to flatten your list of lists and then proceed as normal

```
var test = myData.SelectMany(x => x)
    .Where(x => x.Type == "testType")
    .Select(x => x.Name)
    .Distinct()
    .ToList();
```

Or in query syntax

```
var test = (from subList in myData
            from item in subList
            where item.Type == "testType"
            select item.Name).Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: This is all correct and I've +1'ed, but in the method syntax, you could put the `Where` inside the `SelectMany`... like: `myData.SelectMany(x => x.Where(y => y.Type == "testType").Select(y => y.Name)).Distinct();`. Not that it's any better, but I cringe when I see `x => x` lambdas

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it using query notation:

```
var test= from list in myData
          from e in list
          where e.Type=="testType"
          group e.Name by e.Name into g
          select g.Key;
```

But is better go for one of the @juharr's solutions